# How to get the datalist as an array?

Tags: jquery

My HTML is a datalist with some suggestions to fill somethings.

```
<datalist id="estados">
    <option value="Acre" />
    <option value="Alagoas" />
    <option value="Amazonas" />
    ...
  </datalist>
```

I want to get those as an array, so I can use it when the browser doesn't support this and enable with jQuery UI Autocomplete.

```
["Acre", "Alagoas", "Amazonas" ...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var array = $('#estados option').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VzrHg/

Comment: This should be $('#estados').children('option') instead of your thumbs down child selector. I'm mad at both you and felix.

Comment: @AndyRay - If you're *that* into selector performance, you should forgo the `option` selector completely: `$('#estados').children()` (or even use native DOM methods). In reality though, the difference is negligible at best.

Comment: That's selector performance 101, everyone should know it. This selector will query every option tag on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Also in plain JavaScript you could do this:

```
var options = document.getElementById('estados').getElementsByTagName('option');
var optionVals = [], i = 0;

for (i; i < options.length; i += 1) {
  optionVals.push(options[i].value);
}

console.log(optionVals);
```